# How to change the name (or value) an specific item on a list-group after selecting the item (Bootstrap 3 / c# / ASP .NET)

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need to know how to modify (Change the name) of an list-group (Bootstrap 3). I have a Text box that will have the new name, and of course the list, after selecting the item or pressing a button the name on the Text box needs to be the new name for the item selected, all of this using the code behind.

```
<input runat="server" id="Text2" placeholder="New name" class="form-control" type="text" />

<div runat="server" id="List" class="list-group">
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Sample 1</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Sample 2</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Sample 3</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Sample 4</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Sample 5</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Sample 6</a>
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Sample 7</a>
</div>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button1" class="btn btn-success" Text="Change Name" />
```

So far I've tried the following code + added `runat="server"` and an id to all items in the list.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            BtnaddBtn.Click += BtnaddBtn_Click;
        }

        private void BtnaddBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string test = Text2.Value;
            item1.InnerHtml = test;
        }
```

This code does work and is the expected output, however, i don't know how to make it work like this by pressing the item itself.

Any help, suggestions or edits will be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi and thank you! sorry for the late response, what i'm trying to do is to change the name of a single item in the list, example: I put in the Text box "Example 1" and i select the "Sample 1" in the list, after pressing the button the name would change to "Example 1", Hope this answer is clear enough.

Comment: Ps: I'm trying to make it work, I'll edit my post once i finish trying.

Comment: Just added what I've tried, thanks once again!

Comment: What component in your HTML codes is `item1`? Like you did a code-behind script of: `item1.InnerHtml = test;`.

Comment: Define a list/array variable for the list-group. Use the variable to load the list-group. When clicked, track the position of the item on the list or key of the item.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, i was playing around with other types of lists, a drop down worked the best, again, thanks! Also the ```item1``` id was for one of the items in the list.